# Pisarze - Data analysis task from Polish Olimpiad in Informatics

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, machine-learning, data-science

> You are given 3 well known Polish Books and based on some fragment of text you have to decide whether it's the first one, second or third.
>   Your points are measured by some formula and to achieve 100 points you need to get accuracy greater than 90%.

My solution to solve this problem was to map the most common words and based on that answer, for that solution I've got 70 points but still, I don't know how to approach this problem. Your code may be in Python or C++, [you are given 3 books and program to test your solution](https://sio2.mimuw.edu.pl/c/oi27-1/ca/201/) Inputs are separated with different lengths based on sentences or some amount of words. You are also sure you will not get half-word. [Problem statement](https://szkopul.edu.pl/problemset/problem/v2Y2_UW56ENMcbwP22tkTb7a/site/?key=statement) (only in Polish currently). You can also submit your code there. How can I approach this problem differentlt to get 100 points, are there some Data Sciece algorithms which will help me with that problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int testow,wynik;
string mic,slowo;
map<string,int> s;
int w[100000];
int main(){
s["Winicjusz"]=2;s["Petroniusz"]=2;s["Ligia"]=2;s["Winicjusza"]=2;s["cezara"]=2;s["Ligii"]=2;s["cezar"]=2;s["albowiem"]=2;s["Nero"]=2;s["Ligie"]=2;s["Chilo"]=2;s["Ursus"]=2;s["Akte"]=2;s["Petroniusza"]=2;s["Piotr"]=2;s["Tadeusz"]=1;s["Wojski"]=1;s["Apostol"]=2;s["Eunice"]=2;s["Ancjum"]=2;s["chrzescijanie"]=2;s["Nerona"]=2;s["Pomponia"]=2;s["Pomponii"]=2;s["atrium"]=2;s["Chilona"]=2;s["Ostrianum"]=2;s["Tygellinus"]=2;s["Aulusow"]=2;s["Winicjuszowi"]=2;s["Gerwazy"]=1;s["Poppea"]=2;s["Telimena"]=1;s["Cezar"]=2;s["Aulus"]=2;s["Ligio"]=2;s["Apostola"]=2;s["niemal"]=2;s["niewolnicy"]=2;s["Chilon"]=2;s["Klucznik"]=1;s["Glauka"]=2;s["Robak"]=1;s["Podkomorzy"]=1;s["Tadeusza"]=1;s["bogowie"]=2;s["Tygellina"]=2;s["Ursusa"]=2;s["uczynic"]=2;s["Rykow"]=1;s["Tygellin"]=2;s["pretorianow"]=2;s["uczynil"]=2;s["naokol"]=2;s["Go"]=2;s["Tarsu"]=2;s["cyrku"]=2;s["Litwie"]=1;s["Glaukus"]=2;s["chrzescijaninem"]=2;s["Asesor"]=1;s["Sedziego"]=1;s["Aulusa"]=2;s["Grek"]=2;s["Zali"]=2;s["arenie"]=2;s["Rejent"]=1;s["Zosia"]=1;s["Krotona"]=2;s["cezarem"]=2;s["Chryzotemis"]=2;s["boski"]=2;s["Marku"]=2;s["Winicjuszu"]=2;s["cezarowi"]=2;s["wtenczas"]=1;s["Poppei"]=2;s["triclinium"]=2;s["arene"]=2;s["augustianow"]=2;s["Zosi"]=1;s["Kryspus"]=2;s["lektyki"]=2;s["Horeszkow"]=1;s["Achai"]=2;s["Greka"]=2;s["Petroniuszu"]=2;s["odrzekla"]=2;s["srod"]=1;s["Kroto"]=2;s["Linus"]=2;s["Linusa"]=2;s["Nazariusz"]=2;s["Winicjuszem"]=2;s["czynil"]=2;s["niewolnik"]=2;s["Hrabiego"]=1;s["Jacek"]=1;s["Ligow"]=2;s["Miriam"]=2;s["Palatynie"]=2;s["Seneka"]=2;s["amfiteatrze"]=2;s["wiezieniu"]=2;s["Soplica"]=1;s["Petroniuszowi"]=2;s["Westynus"]=2;s["cezarze"]=2;s["Maciej"]=1;s["Rzekl"]=1;s["Zatybrze"]=2;s["cubiculum"]=2;s["Lig"]=2;s["areny"]=2;s["willi"]=2;s["Soplicow"]=1;s["Grecji"]=2;s["Via"]=2;s["augustianie"]=2;s["dziewice"]=2;s["odnalezc"]=2;s["poczucie"]=2;s["Moskali"]=1;s["Protazy"]=1;s["Chrzescijanie"]=2;s["Grecyna"]=2;s["Neapolis"]=2;s["Plaucjusz"]=2;s["chrzescijanami"]=2;s["Dabrowski"]=1;s["Kryspa"]=2;s["Pomponie"]=2;s["amfiteatr"]=2;s["centurion"]=2;s["legii"]=2;s["lektyke"]=2;s["przerazenia"]=2;s["swiatynie"]=2;s["Dobrzynscy"]=1;s["Baranka"]=2;s["Chilonie"]=2;s["Herkulesa"]=2;s["Miedzianobrody"]=2;s["czynic"]=2;s["igrzysk"]=2;s["meke"]=2;s["ogrodow"]=2;s["rzymski"]=2;s["trybun"]=2;s["Chrzciciel"]=1;s["Maciek"]=1;s["Soplicowie"]=1;s["Stolnik"]=1;s["Wojskiego"]=1;s["Augusty"]=2;s["Jowisza"]=2;s["Palatynu"]=2;s["Watyniusz"]=2;s["chrzescijanom"]=2;s["gladiatorow"]=2;s["igrzyska"]=2;s["pretorianie"]=2;s["przeto"]=2;s["sestercji"]=2;s["tunike"]=2;s["uczynila"]=2;s["Sedziemu"]=1;s["Sedzio"]=1;s["Bogowie"]=2;s["Chilonowi"]=2;s["Palatyn"]=2;s["miluje"]=2;s["podium"]=2;s["wiedz"]=2;s["Plut"]=1;s["Zosie"]=1;s["Aulusowi"]=2;s["Lukan"]=2;s["Mu"]=2;s["Porta"]=2;s["Scewinus"]=2;s["Senecjo"]=2;s["Ursusem"]=2;s["Zatybrzu"]=2;s["augustianami"]=2;s["lekarz"]=2;s["lwow"]=2;s["niechybnie"]=2;s["nieprzyjaciolmi"]=2;s["pozarem"]=2;s["toge"]=2;s["zakladniczka"]=2;s["zgube"]=2;s["Dobrzynski"]=1;s["charty"]=1;s["Aulusowie"]=2;s["Azji"]=2;s["Grecyny"]=2;s["Niego"]=2;s["Polluksa"]=2;s["Tuliusz"]=2;s["Vicus"]=2;s["Witeliusz"]=2;s["barbarzyncy"]=2;s["cnote"]=2;s["jeno"]=2;s["patrycjusz"]=2;s["poszukiwania"]=2;s["wigilow"]=2;s["wyznawcow"]=2;s["wyzwolency"]=2;s["Kropiciel"]=1;s["bernardyna"]=1;s["rzecze"]=1;s["strzelcy"]=1;s["Aulusom"]=2;s["Niewolnicy"]=2;s["Seneki"]=2;s["Tygellinowi"]=2;s["Zbawiciel"]=2;s["nakazuje"]=2;s["niewolnic"]=2;s["niewolnikom"]=2;s["odnajdzie"]=2;s["pochodni"]=2;s["rozpoznac"]=2;s["wiezienie"]=2;s["zadzy"]=2;s["Buchman"]=1;s["Jankiel"]=1;s["Stolnika"]=1;s["Telimenie"]=1;s["Telimeny"]=1;s["krzykneli"]=1;s["kwestarz"]=1;s["rapier"]=1;s["Chilonem"]=2;s["Eurycjusza"]=2;s["Liga"]=2;s["Niger"]=2;s["Ostii"]=2;s["Petroniuszem"]=2;s["Plaucjusza"]=2;s["Tygellinem"]=2;s["Westy"]=2;s["Wierze"]=2;s["Zatybrza"]=2;s["chrzescijanach"]=2;s["chrzescijanina"]=2;s["cytry"]=2;s["opieka"]=2;s["peplum"]=2;s["pochodnie"]=2;s["potu"]=2;s["szmaragd"]=2;s["togi"]=2;s["Hrabie"]=1;s["Klucznika"]=1;s["Konewka"]=1;s["Macka"]=1;s["Majorze"]=1;s["Moskal"]=1;s["Moskala"]=1;s["Robaka"]=1;s["biezy"]=1;s["karabele"]=1;s["kedy"]=1;s["polowanie"]=1;s["powiecie"]=1;s["Ahenobarba"]=2;s["Gor"]=2;s["Grecy"]=2;s["Kastora"]=2;s["Kryspinilla"]=2;s["Kwartus"]=2;s["Pomyslal"]=2;s["Poppee"]=2;s["Rubria"]=2;s["Rzymem"]=2;s["Tlumy"]=2;s["Tullianum"]=2;s["boga"]=2;s["carissime"]=2;s["czuwac"]=2;s["czynila"]=2;s["dobrem"]=2;s["dochodzily"]=2;s["filozof"]=2;s["kaplani"]=2;s["kaplanow"]=2;s["lutnie"]=2;s["milowac"]=2;s["niesc"]=2;s["oraz"]=2;s["orszak"]=2;s["owce"]=2;s["plaszcza"]=2;s["prefekt"]=2;s["rzymskiego"]=2;s["rzymskim"]=2;s["skrecili"]=2;s["uczynie"]=2;s["zmartwychwstal"]=2;s["Bernardyn"]=1;s["Dobrzynskich"]=1;s["Iz"]=1;s["Litwa"]=1;s["Polski"]=1;s["Rejentem"]=1;s["Scyzoryk"]=1;s["Soplice"]=1;s["chartow"]=1;s["jegry"]=1;s["rury"]=1;s["stola"]=1;s["tem"]=1;s["Atacynus"]=2;s["Augustianie"]=2;s["Dolow"]=2;s["Italii"]=2;s["Kwirytow"]=2;s["Plaucjuszow"]=2;s["Rufiusa"]=2;s["Subury"]=2;s["Tybru"]=2;s["Ursusowi"]=2;s["Wydalo"]=2;s["barbarzyncow"]=2;s["bogiem"]=2;s["cyprysow"]=2;s["dymy"]=2;s["lektyka"]=2;s["muly"]=2;s["nocami"]=2;s["oddychac"]=2;s["oddzialy"]=2;s["plonace"]=2;s["pozarze"]=2;s["przybrany"]=2;s["spiewem"]=2;s["tegoz"]=2;s["trybunie"]=2;s["uczt"]=2;s["westalka"]=2;s["wystapic"]=2;s["wyznawcy"]=2;s["zaulki"]=2;s["By"]=1;s["Hrabi"]=1;s["Prusak"]=1;s["Rebajlo"]=1;s["Rejenta"]=1;s["Rykowa"]=1;s["Soplicy"]=1;s["Srod"]=1;s["Wtenczas"]=1;s["bernardyn"]=1;s["jegrow"]=1;s["kropic"]=1;s["litewskich"]=1;s["mopanku"]=1;s["pono"]=1;s["ramiony"]=1;s["zascianku"]=1;s["Ahenobarbus"]=2;s["Albanskich"]=2;s["Baiae"]=2;s["Benewentu"]=2;s["Christo"]=2;s["Chrystusie"]=2;s["Cuchnacych"]=2;s["Domicjusz"]=2;s["Emporium"]=2;s["Eurycjusz"]=2;s["Kampanii"]=2;s["Kapitol"]=2;s["Krotonem"]=2;s["Merkurego"]=2;s["Nazariusza"]=2;s["Neronowi"]=2;s["Terpnos"]=2;s["Tyber"]=2;s["Widocznym"]=2;s["Widziano"]=2;s["biodrach"]=2;s["czyniono"]=2;s["kaganek"]=2;s["lektyce"]=2;s["marmuru"]=2;s["odnalazl"]=2;s["oliwy"]=2;s["pacholeta"]=2;s["plonacego"]=2;s["podniosly"]=2;s["porywac"]=2;s["prefektem"]=2;s["pretorianom"]=2;s["robotnika"]=2;s["rozpocznie"]=2;s["senatorowie"]=2;s["tabliczki"]=2;s["tchnieniem"]=2;s["tejze"]=2;s["troski"]=2;s["trybuna"]=2;s["tryumf"]=2;s["uczynilo"]=2;s["uniesienie"]=2;s["wszechmocny"]=2;s["wyzwolenca"]=2;s["zlotowlosa"]=2;s["Asesora"]=1;s["Bracie"]=1;s["Chrzciciela"]=1;s["Dobrzynie"]=1;s["Ktorych"]=1;s["Litwy"]=1;s["Moskalow"]=1;s["Pluta"]=1;s["Podkomorzego"]=1;s["Pyta"]=1;s["Sak"]=1;s["Scyzorykiem"]=1;s["Skoluba"]=1;s["Soplicowa"]=1;s["Stoja"]=1;s["konopie"]=1;s["lowach"]=1;s["mysliwcow"]=1;s["ochmistrzyni"]=1;s["polskie"]=1;s["strzelby"]=1;s["traw"]=1;s["wloscian"]=1;s["wszerz"]=1;s["zareczyny"]=1;s["Afer"]=2;s["Agryppy"]=2;s["Arycji"]=2;s["Augusto"]=2;s["Benewencie"]=2;s["Cezara"]=2;s["Cie"]=2;s["Cumae"]=2;s["Cyrku"]=2;s["Demas"]=2;s["Diodor"]=2;s["Flawiusz"]=2;s["Fortuna"]=2;s["Glaukos"]=2;s["Grecja"]=2;s["Hades"]=2;s["Karynach"]=2;s["Ligowie"]=2;s["Markus"]=2;s["Mniejszej"]=2;s["Salaria"]=2;s["Tyberiusza"]=2;s["Tygellinie"]=2;s["Uczyn"]=2;s["Watyniusza"]=2;s["Witeliusza"]=2;s["Zrozumial"]=2;s["augustianina"]=2;s["centuriona"]=2;s["cesarskiego"]=2;s["chrzest"]=2;s["czynili"]=2;s["dech"]=2;s["doszli"]=2;s["fontannie"]=2;s["kleknal"]=2;s["ligijski"]=2;s["mirtow"]=2;s["morduja"]=2;s["naloznica"]=2;s["nieprzebrane"]=2;s["obozu"]=2;s["oczekiwania"]=2;s["odleglych"]=2;s["ogarniac"]=2;s["okazywal"]=2;s["patrycjusza"]=2;s["plomienia"]=2;s["podpalic"]=2;s["podziemia"]=2;s["pomste"]=2;s["posilku"]=2;s["pozogi"]=2;s["prawdzie"]=2;s["przebraniu"]=2;s["przybrane"]=2;s["przypuszczenia"]=2;s["rozpoznal"]=2;s["rzez"]=2;s["rzut"]=2;s["senatu"]=2;s["velarium"]=2;s["widzom"]=2;s["wladca"]=2;s["wokol"]=2;s["wskaze"]=2;s["zaslubic"]=2;s["znad"]=2;s["Biezy"]=1;s["Brzytewka"]=1;s["Brzytwa"]=1;s["Dawal"]=1;s["Dobyl"]=1;s["Hejze"]=1;s["Hrabiemu"]=1;s["Jacku"]=1;s["Kedy"]=1;s["Kniaziewicz"]=1;s["Kropidlo"]=1;s["Kusego"]=1;s["Kusy"]=1;s["Mopanku"]=1;s["Moskale"]=1;s["Polszcze"]=1;s["Radziwill"]=1;s["Rozga"]=1;s["Rymsza"]=1;s["Sokola"]=1;s["Strzelcy"]=1;s["Telimene"]=1;s["Zgoda"]=1;s["ascka"]=1;s["chwaly"]=1;s["drazki"]=1;s["dumania"]=1;s["dziedzica"]=1;s["kontusza"]=1;s["kryjomu"]=1;s["kurki"]=1;s["lice"]=1;s["liku"]=1;s["mysliwi"]=1;s["mysliwych"]=1;s["nazbyt"]=1;s["oblawa"]=1;s["ogary"]=1;s["owad"]=1;s["pleban"]=1;s["plebana"]=1;s["polowania"]=1;s["pospieszal"]=1;s["ptastwo"]=1;s["rzadka"]=1;s["sasiedzie"]=1;s["szabli"]=1;s["tabaki"]=1;s["wasc"]=1;s["wiwat"]=1;s["zawzdy"]=1;s["Apostolow"]=2;s["Apostolowi"]=2;s["Appijskiej"]=2;s["Aula"]=2;s["Chilonides"]=2;s["Corioli"]=2;s["Egiptu"]=2;s["Galow"]=2;s["Grekow"]=2;s["Juniusz"]=2;s["Kalwia"]=2;s["Klaudiusza"]=2;s["Neronem"]=2;s["Nerwa"]=2;s["Nomentana"]=2;s["Portuensis"]=2;s["Rzymian"]=2;s["Stroze"]=2;s["Suburze"]=2;s["Urbanie"]=2;s["Ustrinum"]=2;s["Wschodzie"]=2;s["Zeusie"]=2;s["bluszczow"]=2;s["bramami"]=2;s["cudnych"]=2;s["cyrk"]=2;
    cin>>testow;
    cin.ignore(1);
    for(int j=0;j<testow;j++){
        getline(cin,mic);
        slowo="";
        wynik = 0;
        //int i=0;
        //while(mic[i] != roz)
        for(int i = 0; i <mic.size(); i++){
            if(mic[i]>='0' && mic[i]<='9'){
                slowo+=mic[i];
            }
            else if(mic[i]>='A' && mic[i]<='Z'){
                slowo+=mic[i];
            }
            else if(mic[i]>='a' && mic[i]<='z'){
                  slowo+=mic[i];
            }
            else{
                if(s.find(slowo)!=s.end()){
                    w[j]=s.find(slowo)->second;

                }
                slowo="";

            }
        }

    }


    for(int i=0;i<testow;i++){

        if(w[i]==0){
            cout<<"Prus\n";
        }
        else if(w[i]==1){
            cout<<"Mickiewicz\n";
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Sienkiewicz\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From what I can tell you just need to store the books content in a string and search for the fragment in it. That should give you optimal answers. The only difficult part of this is to figure out what the fastest possible search algorithm is (if time is even a constraint).

Comment: The source code has to be smaller than 10 kB. Books sizes are Mickiewicz.txt 401KB, Prus.txt 1.6MB, Sienkiewicz.txt 1.1MB. Also time limit is 10s per test.

Comment: @JakubSwistak The size of external files you read does *not* impact the size of your source code. And 10s is an eternity for a problem like this. It should take milliseconds once the data is read into memory (which should also be doable in sub-second times on any hardware produced since 1960).

Comment: But you are not able to read external files!

Comment: Your problem statement seems unclear. So you are given the books and have to write one program specifically for these books that will then have to identify text fragments without being provided the book contents and the source code's size must not exceed 10kB? Please give a precise problem statement. I also think that the question is too broad for this site.

Comment: "you are given the books and have to write one program specifically for these books that will then have to identify text fragments without being provided the book contents and the source code's size must not exceed 10kB?" - exactly. That's the whole problem statement. Why do you think that's too brad?

Comment: What he means is that you are only given those books during preparation of your program. For test phase you only provide source limited to `10kb` size (and you cannot bundle those books with it due to `3mb` size of texts). Is that correct interpretation? Books are by no means source code but I assume those cannot be added with answer, right?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non-polish readers: **you are given those books only when preparing your solution, you won't have access to them during test**. If you try to bundle them with binary somehow those would exceed `10kb` limit hence you need to compress information somehow.

I would go for [`Naive Bayes`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) classifier by default for a simple solution .

Due to time constraint I would go a little bit different route though.

### Data preparation

Read all files in and tokenize them. Would be easiest with Python's `split` functionality (and whole program would be easiest, time constraint probably won't be a problem). Split on whitespace and punctuation as those are mostly noise and are not representative of texts.

Now calculate how often each of the tokens (words) occurs in each text, e.g. `dog` occured `15` times in first text and `3` times in another. Save those in three separate dictionaries, if the size of `dict` exceeds `10kb` remove words occurring least frequently and adjust accordingly.

### Classifier for test phase

Use `3 unsigned long` variables to keep results for each texts to keep overflow in check (it should be enough).

For every input text split it just like above.

For every word check in dictionaries how often those occured for each text and add this to one of `3` result variables. If it doesn't exist just add `0`.

Finally return text which gathered "most points" this way. This should get quite a good score.

### Better solution

Naive Bayes with probabilities would work much better but given competition constraints I don't think it is a viable solution.

To do it, you would have to calculate probability of each word for each text and use `log` operstions during summation to avoid aforementioned overflow, just throwing it out for you to consider, doable but probably overkill.

Comment: How will dictionary work? It will be c++ map where key = word and value is a number? Cause for that it will run out of space really fast and will get similar amount of points. My solution was to create dictionary with the most common words specific for first or second book and if none was found print third one.

Comment: @JakubSwistak Dictionary can be of any size you want, including `10kb` (around `200` most common words would be within the limit). Furthermore you could encode it as a matrix, where each row corresponds to a text, see how [`sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) works. Your current solution relies on the assumption of specific words existing in test case which usually won't be the case (and wouold return the third one). Approaches are different and so would be the scores.